# Gateway legacy mssql 2000 application for use with mssql 2017

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-server-2017

I exhumed a legacy .NET application that used MSSQL 2000 and I want to use it in an environment that uses MSSQL 2017.

No source code is available.

I'm thinking about some kind of "gateway" application (like a proxy of some sort) that "translates" the various query from 2000 to 2017.

Does anyone know if this can be done and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running the app against a SQL 2017 database in the oldest available database compatibility level for that version (110 for SQL 2008)? SQL Server is mostly backwards compatible.

Comment: The application is not working on other database than SQL 2000. Tried to upgrade the databases to 2005 and it's not connecting, no clue on what's happening so I wanted to use the "gateway" option.

Comment: you can probably write a simple TDS proxy to at least catch what the issue is. Something like this perhaps: https://github.com/tech-software/TDSProxy